# How to set umask and dos2unix when checking out on Linux?

Tags: svn, umask, dos2unix

How can I configure my `svn` client (`/bin/svn`) to check out files under a default permission setting (e.g. `umask 0022` or `chmod 755`) as well as to instantly convert them from DOS file format? Currently, I do `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 1):

> check out files under a default permission setting (e.g. umask 0022 or chmod 755)

Set up [your shell appropriately](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html) or wrap the svn client in a shell script that takes care of the work after performing the checkout.

> instantly convert them from DOS file format?

Set `svn:eol-style` to `native` on your files to get appropriate EOL markers based on the host OS when checking out. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.eol-style